# Intern test framework: Command + v for pasting contents from clipboard does not work

Tags: selenium, intern, leadfoot

I have contents in the clipboard which I would like to paste to a textbox.
When I try

```
.click()
.pressKeys(['\uE03D', 'v'])
```

it does not paste the contents to the textbox. All other special keys work. For example, for using shift key, when I do

```
.pressKeys(['\uE008', 'v'])
```

it prints 'V' as expected.

Any advice on this would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like:

```
.click().pressKeys(Keys.Control + "v")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you've already got your answer because I think you're the same person that [posted this question verbatim](https://github.com/theintern/leadfoot/issues/42) on the Issue Tracker for The Intern, but for those people looking at this SO ticket...

This is a known bug that isn't broken in The Intern.  It's a [Selenium bug](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/8555), and by proxy a bug in all the Mac OS X implementations for Safari ([here's a related bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=30) on the ChromeDriver issue tracker).  It appears that these commands don't work on a Mac due to the Command key issuing OS-level events that never trickle into the Javascript engine run by these browsers.

I wouldn't hold out hope for a fix because it looks like it's been an active bug since 2012...